# Как присвоить переменной уже созданную Windows.Forms.Form в .NET?

Tags: тестирование, powershell, автоматизация

Стоит задача по автоматизации тестирования GUI-шных приложений в Windows. Для этого предполагаю использование скрипта на **PowerShell**. Как я себе это представляю: через PS открываем GUI-приложение (написанное на Python-е), присваиваем созданную форму новой переменной $currentForm, после чего работаем с ней:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$currentForm = ???
# работаем с переменной
```

Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как именно это можно сделать, в связи с чем и прошу помощи :)

Если есть другие, более разумные, пути решения задачи, то с удовольствием на них посмотрю и буду Вам крайне признателен и благодарен!

Answer (score 3):

Вот так:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$currentForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

Можно посмотреть доступные свойства объекта формы, а также их текущие значения, вот так:

```
Write-Output $currentForm
```

Результат выполнения:

```
AcceptButton                       : 
ActiveMdiChild                     : 
AllowTransparency                  : False
AutoScale                          : True
AutoScaleBaseSize                  : {Width=5, Height=13}
AutoScroll                         : False
AutoSize                           : False
AutoSizeMode                       : GrowOnly
AutoValidate                       : EnablePreventFocusChange
BackColor                          : Color [Control]
FormBorderStyle                    : Sizable
CancelButton                       : 
ClientSize                         : {Width=284, Height=262}
ControlBox                         : True
DesktopBounds                      : {X=125,Y=125,Width=300,Height=300}
DesktopLocation                    : {X=125,Y=125}
DialogResult                       : None
HelpButton                         : False
Icon                               : (Значок)
IsMdiChild                         : False
IsMdiContainer                     : False
IsRestrictedWindow                 : False
KeyPreview                         : False
Location                           : {X=125,Y=125}
MaximumSize                        : {Width=0, Height=0}
MainMenuStrip                      : 
Margin                             : {Left=3,Top=3,Right=3,Bottom=3}
Menu                               : 
MinimumSize                        : {Width=0, Height=0}
MaximizeBox                        : True
MdiChildren                        : {}
MdiParent                          : 
MergedMenu                         : 
MinimizeBox                        : True
Modal                              : False
Opacity                            : 1
OwnedForms                         : {}
Owner                              : 
RestoreBounds                      : {X=125,Y=125,Width=300,Height=300}
RightToLeftLayout                  : False
ShowInTaskbar                      : True
ShowIcon                           : True
Size                               : {Width=300, Height=300}
SizeGripStyle                      : Auto
StartPosition                      : WindowsDefaultLocation
TabIndex                           : 0
TabStop                            : True
Text                               : 
TopLevel                           : True
TopMost                            : False
TransparencyKey                    : Color [Empty]
WindowState                        : Normal
AutoScaleDimensions                : {Width=0, Height=0}
AutoScaleMode                      : Inherit
BindingContext                     : {}
ActiveControl                      : 
CurrentAutoScaleDimensions         : {Width=0, Height=0}
ParentForm                         : 
AutoScrollMargin                   : {Width=0, Height=0}
AutoScrollPosition                 : {X=0,Y=0}
AutoScrollMinSize                  : {Width=0, Height=0}
DisplayRectangle                   : {X=0,Y=0,Width=284,Height=262}
HorizontalScroll                   : System.Windows.Forms.HScrollProperties
VerticalScroll                     : System.Windows.Forms.VScrollProperties
DockPadding                        : 
AccessibilityObject                : ControlAccessibleObject: Owner = System.Windows.Forms.Form, Text: 
AccessibleDefaultActionDescription : 
AccessibleDescription              : 
AccessibleName                     : 
AccessibleRole                     : Default
AllowDrop                          : False
Anchor                             : Top, Left
AutoScrollOffset                   : {X=0,Y=0}
LayoutEngine                       : System.Windows.Forms.Layout.DefaultLayout
BackgroundImage                    : 
BackgroundImageLayout              : Tile
Bottom                             : 425
Bounds                             : {X=125,Y=125,Width=300,Height=300}
CanFocus                           : False
CanSelect                          : False
Capture                            : False
CausesValidation                   : True
ClientRectangle                    : {X=0,Y=0,Width=284,Height=262}
CompanyName                        : Microsoft Corporation
ContainsFocus                      : False
ContextMenu                        : 
ContextMenuStrip                   : 
Controls                           : {}
Created                            : False
Cursor                             : [Cursor: Default]
DataBindings                       : {}
IsDisposed                         : False
Disposing                          : False
Dock                               : None
Enabled                            : True
Focused                            : False
Font                               : [Font: Name=Microsoft Sans Serif, Size=8,25, Units=3, GdiCharSet=204, GdiVerticalFont=F
                                     alse]
ForeColor                          : Color [ControlText]
Handle                             : 10029516
HasChildren                        : False
Height                             : 300
IsHandleCreated                    : True
InvokeRequired                     : False
IsAccessible                       : False
IsMirrored                         : False
Left                               : 125
Name                               : 
Parent                             : 
ProductName                        : Microsoft® .NET Framework
ProductVersion                     : 4.0.30319.34251
RecreatingHandle                   : False
Region                             : 
Right                              : 425
RightToLeft                        : No
Site                               : 
Tag                                : 
Top                                : 125
TopLevelControl                    : System.Windows.Forms.Form, Text: 
UseWaitCursor                      : False
Visible                            : False
Width                              : 300
WindowTarget                       : System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow
PreferredSize                      : {Width=16, Height=38}
Padding                            : {Left=0,Top=0,Right=0,Bottom=0}
ImeMode                            : NoControl
Container                          :
```

Мы также можем изменить текущие свойства объекта, допустим, изменить размер формы установив значение высоты и ширины в 100:

```
$currentForm.Height = 100
$currentForm.Width = 100
```

Вызов окна выполняется методом **ShowDialog**, вот так:

```
$currentForm.ShowDialog()
```

В интернете есть множество примеров, описывающих создание тех или иных форм с использованием PowerShell. Например, [Windows PowerShell Tip: Creating a Custom Input Box](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx)